# Windows Phone 8, custom RoadMaps

Tags: windows-phone-8, bing-maps, here-api

I would like to implement in a Windows Phone 8 application, a map application, but using only custom roads, without any existing roads.

Examples of this being useful : private areas roads, or special vehicles roads like bicycles and more.

Do you know how i could implement something like that ?

Comment: what does the documentation say ?

Comment: There is no documentation related to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Style property to a MapStlye of None:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapstyle.aspx

This will hide the base road maps. You can then overlay your own road data in a couple of different ways. One method is to simply create polylines for the roads and pushpins/MapIcon for the labels.

Another option is to create a tile layer with your road data on it and load that up.

Comment: Yes, just to hide the roads, is not a big deal, but i don't want just to draw some lines. I want to use my own data for navigation, address searching, etc.

Comment: That would require building out your own mapping platform. The Bing Maps API doesn't expose any method for you to replace it's data with your own.